# NSXML parser read attributes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I have a element that is repeating and i need to read it's attributes and send them to the delegate

the xml is:

```
<special>
   <day date="22/04/2011" name="Easter Friday">Closed</day>
   <day date="23/04/2011" name="Easter Saturday">10:00-16:00</day>
   <day date="24/04/2011" name="Easter Sunday">Closed</day>
   <day date="25/04/2011" name="Anzac Day">13:00-17:00</day>
   <day date="26/04/2011" name="Easter Tuesday">09:00-18:00</day>
</special>
```

i only get to past the last attributes for date and name to the delegate and i know why is this happening but i dont know how to fix it. can someone help me

here is my objective C code

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"special"]) {
        storeAppDelegate.openingHoursSpecialDelegate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"day"]) {
        openingHoursView = [[OpeningHoursView alloc] init];
        openingHoursView.name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"];
        openingHoursView.date = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"date"];
      }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"special"])
        return;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"day"]){
        [storeAppDelegate.openingHoursSpecialDelegate addObject:openingHoursView];
        [openingHoursView release];
        openingHoursView = nil;     

    }   
}
```

openingHoursSpecialDelegate is a mutable array in the app delegate and OpeningHoursView is a NSObject that has name and date as strings in it in another class. They also get the value of the app delegate and it is also only the last read value for "date" and "name" attributes from the XML file .
I'm working with NSXML parser 
so again my question is how to get "openingHoursView.name" and "openingHoursView.date" to write every value they get to openingHoursSpecialDelegate and not overwrite them as it happens now

Comment: from where to set object in attributeDict

Comment: dont really understand your question. Please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find anything wrong with the code. I've put the above code into a small test project (with minor changes to make it run standalone), and it runs fine for me.

> Array (
>       "Easter Friday, 22/04/2011",
>       "Easter Saturday, 23/04/2011",
>       "Easter Sunday, 24/04/2011",
>       "Anzac Day, 25/04/2011",
>       "Easter Tuesday, 26/04/2011" )

[Example project](http://www.pointandhost.com/test2.zip)

You'll need to change the path I've hardcoded in the class test2AppDelegate, to point to a file containing the XML you posted above.

Comment: Yes i know that this kind of parsing works. I'm trying to get the value to a third class and it is in iOS not MacOS. I don't really know the difference Never worked pure cocoa but. I've tried to pass the delegate to another file and i cant. Please advice

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your problem. Can you upload an xcode project that exhibits the issue? Without seeing more code, I can't find anything wrong with what you have. (BTW, it should work the same in MacOS and iOS.)

Comment: my problem is that i have one file (class) that is XMLparser and reads the XML file then it sends the values into AppDelegate and here i get only the last value and not all of them.Any way thx for your time and help

Comment: I'm sorry for this posted question all was fine i had mixed up some var names and that was the whole confusion thx any way for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Already i have workout this problem in my project.But i am using libxml2.
The problem is (day node)  you have to set the 5 different value to same key (day) thats why you get last attribute .